# Postgre Crosstab Function with inner join has mismatch values

Tags: postgresql, inner-join, crosstab

The postgre crosstab query result to mismatch column values. Here is the code below  using inner join.

**Postgre Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
transaction_date,payee_name,v1.voucher_number,cash_advance,cash_on_hand FROM 
vouchers v1
        INNER JOIN(
        select * 
        from crosstab ('select voucher_number, particular, sum(debit) from 
                  vouchers GROUP BY voucher_number,particular ORDER BY 1,2')
                          as final_result("voucher_number" integer,
                                          "cash_advance" float,
                                          "cash_on_hand" float
                                          )) as v2
         ON v1.voucher_number = v2.voucher_number
```

**Query Result**
Note: The highlighted values shown in the image below are interchanged

[image]

Database Table (vouchers)

Note: The database table below shows the right values for each row. The highlighted values are correct but are interchanged using the crosstab query shown above.

[image]

This query return the right values:

```
select * from crosstab ('select voucher_number, particular, sum(debit) from 
        vouchers GROUP BY voucher_number,particular ORDER BY 1,2')
                          as final_result("voucher_number" integer,
                                          "cash_advance" float,
                                          "cash_on_hand" float
                                          )
```

What is the problem with my code above using the inner join? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: why tag laravel?

Comment: sorry. we removed it already. Can you help us on this?

Comment: The result you claim is in error in fact matches the database values you claim are correct. Furthermore all other voucher number also follow the same pattern, therefor the query is consistent. This implies not query but the data value  (debit column) for the specific voucher that is reversed. Cannot actually run the queries as data presented in a picture. If you want those evaluated re-post your data as text.